# Npm build removing Angular's @Injectable decorator

Tags: angular, npm, package, decorator, typescript-decorator

I'm trying to create a small helper package for Angular, but I've encountered a bit of an issue.
I have an exported class that is an Angular service, so it has the `@Injectable()` decorator on it.

However, whenever I run `npm run build` the compiled class I have in my `dist` doesn't have the decorator, which causes issues with classes that inherit from it. I've set the `experimentalDecorators` flag in my `tsconfig.json` to true as I've seen recommended in other threads, but it didn't have any effect.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, hope you all have a great week.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the typescript code that accepts decorators is transpiled to javascript which does not have decorators, this happens when doing the Angular npm run build